# How can I search a number in O(1) average complexity

Tags: algorithm, analysis

I know that we can search a number in linear search with O (n)  time complexity if no key is present and the complexity is O (1) in best cases. 
What will be the search algorithm if I want to find a number at a particular average case?

Comment: It seems that you can only get O(1) if the element is located at the first position you look. That can be done with a hash, or in the case of an integer search, maintaining an array where each index contains a flag indicating whether that index is part of your data set (or how many times it occurs). That could be prohibitively expensive (memory-wise) if you have a large range of possible values. Wiki (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_search) indicates that the expected (average) cost of a linear search is O(n). In a real implementation, it'll be faster to sort the data, then binary search.

Comment: @3Dave you can also get O(1) with a constant upper bound of time spent, which can include far more work than being located at the first position you look and which allows for many other solutions than a simple huge array or hash (which generally will have your program looking at potentially quite a lot of positions before finding the element).

Comment: *The complexity is `O(1)` in best cases* - That statement is wrong, or at least not what you wanted to say. Big-O must always include all cases. A case-specific analysis means restricting the type of input to a certain type. It is `O(1)` for the case where your restriction is that the number to search for always appears before a constant index, no matter how big the input is. So if you could say *the search is always finished after at least 10 lookups, even if the data is 1 million entries long*. What you probably want is a hashed structure/index. It can answer `contains` in `O(1)`.

Comment: @Zabuza big O doesn't need to include all cases, it is just a notation about function growth. You can do best/worst/average case analysis and use big O notation for that

Comment: @c2huc2hu Wrt what OP says, it does. You first fix a case, i.e. the input type. And then you are bounded to the worst execution in this case. The definition in Big-O says `forall`, not `exists`. If there is just a single execution which is slow, the Big-O is bounded by that. Case analysis has nothing to do with that and OP likely used the term wrong, since its meant to be used for input structure/type restriction. As explained before. In any case, it's just a note and advice that there might be a misunderstanding here.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that your current solution is a simple linear search, which you are correct is O(n) (not O(1), as this is only one isolated case with 1/n probability to occur).

A better solution to find a number in what I assume is sorted array of numbers would be to use a binary search. (Even if your array isn't sorted, if you're performing a significant number of lookups, it could be worth it to sort your numbers with an O(n) sort, like radix sort, then continue to run binary search on your sorted array)

The concept behind a binary search is to continually compare arrays' middle elements with the target value, and recursively search the half of the current that would contain the target element, returning if the value is found at any point.

By continually discarding the halves of the arrays that can not contain the target value, binary search has a time complexity of O(log n), significantly better than O(n).

Here's a great resource for this:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-search/

Good luck!